# How to print something so that if it is nil, it will print nil - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I always use NSLog to print out contents of objects when I am debugging my iOS applications. But any time I come across a "nil" object, the program crashes. In Java, if an object is null, it will print "null". Is there a way to do this in Objective-C?

Comment: That's strange. It shouldn't crash. It should just print `(null)`.

Comment: Could you paste your `NSLog()` calls?

Comment: I'll wager he uses `NSLog(theObject);` instead of `NSLog(@"%@", theObject);`.

Comment: you're wager is wrong. I use NSLog(@"%@",theObject);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
if (questionableObject == nil)  {
   NSLog(@"questionableObject is nil.");
} else {
   NSLog(@"questionableObject is: %@", questionableObject);
}
```

I've only really run into this problem when I send a message to an object inside the NSLog parameter list that uses a nil object as a parameter.  Something like this:

```
if (questionableObject == nil)  {
   NSLog(@"questionableObject is nil.");
} else {
   NSLog(@"result is: %@", [something someMessage:questionableObject]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "print out contents of objects"? If you're dereferencing a nil pointer, that'll cause a problem. If you're just printing the pointer, that should be OK. You can also send messages to nil without problem, so you could do this:

```
NSLog(@"theObject is: %@", [theObject description]);
```